# Where should i store image files such that its accessible from `Gallary` on Android or IOS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework. Where should i store image files such that its accessible from `Gallary` on Android or IOS.

I checked this https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html#where-to-store-files but could not find my answer.